# How to do REST POST request validation for ID - (Entity ID should be null in this case even if they inject in request)

Tags: java, spring, validation, post, jsr

How to validate the below situation,

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Idea {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column
  @Size(min=1,max=10)
  private String title;
}
```

**POST REQ:** (Valid Input) - Properly inserts the data

> {
>       "title":"sample"  }

**POST REQ:** (InValid Input) - Trying to update the data for the ID in POST

> { "id":1, "title":"sample"   }

How to validate the above situation when only on post request happens then the input should have a non ID field or id field with null? like @Null or @NotNull validations.

Note: I have to use the same entity for GET/PUT(should allow id value) as well